# Is there a way to kill and restart a Subroutine call if it is taking too long in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

So I am using this library ImageMagick off of codeplex to **read()** in images from a URL. For some reason this function call may hang from 10 to 27 seconds often (every 90 seconds or so). This is too long as I am trying to display **fresh** camera images to my customers every 10 seconds.  I should also mention that I am calling the routine to grab the images from a **timer event**. This whole subroutine that I am calling from the timer could be squashed and restarted if that helps. However, it is the Read() function that is hanging in this case.

```
grabImages() ‘Called from a Timer event

    Dim MagickImageCamera As MagickImage

    ‘Read() call hangs occasionally. 
    MagickImageCamera.Read("http://111.222.111.222/camera111.jpg") 

    ‘Do stuff
End Sub
```

I should also point out that when the Read() function is locked up I am able to go to the URL of the jpeg in a web browser and **refresh the image just fine**.

Comment: If it used a background worker it may not matter how long it takes and you could cancel it if it did

Comment: Sorry not sure if I understand: _you could cancel it if it did_?

Comment: @OffTheGold he means you could use a background worker (structure for background tasks with multithreading) to call grabImages. You should do so anyways, since laggy GUIs are very annoying. Your plan is to trigger all 5-10 seconds a new request for getting a picture, add an event or poll to see if results are there and can be shown. If it takes more time then maybe a second request is active at the same time, but thats all, zero lag for your GUi